# Multiple Site (Application) Windows Authentication (IIS 7)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, integrated-authentication

We have multiple web sites that need to process DOMAIN authentication in Windows.  There's only one server but multiple sites.

For example:
s1.domain.com
s2.domain.com
s3.domain.com

All of which want a single sign-on.  Simple, except the login dialog only can appear once.

So we need a cross web site integrated authentication.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Integrated authentication will work as long as integrated authentication works.

IE is probably prompting because:

- the target site name contains dots, and
- the target site isn't in the Local Intranet Zone
- and possibly that the target site is being proxied (due to #1 or resulting in #2 or because of WPAD etc)

Then there's the Kerberos issue - i.e. if you require Kerberos, you'll need SPNs configured for that domain name.

But fundamentally, IE should provide transparent logon with the logged-on user's credentials to any site it considers part of the Local Intranet zone, with default settings applied to it.

Note Trusted Sites *sounds* better, but it doesn't permit automatic logon by default. From memory.

Comment: We'll try using IE.  We've been using Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox support integrated authentication.  For firefox you need to set network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris and network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris in about:config.  Not sure if you need to configure Chrome.